# Three,js: Problem when trying to make a sphere move with a bounded sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js and having trouble when trying to animate a sphere to move through a space.

I am creating a new Sphere and using `new THREE.Vector3().randomDirection()`; to make it move. The sphere is supposed to be moving in a bounded sphere for collision detection. When I add     `ballbb.copy(ball.geometry.boundingSphere).applyMatrix4(ball.matrixWorld)` to the code to make the bounded Sphere move with the sphere, the sphere stops moving.

```
const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(sphere,sphereMaterial)
ball.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
ball.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
ball.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;

ball.userData.vel = new THREE.Vector3().randomDirection();

var ballbb = new THREE.Sphere(ball.position, 70)
scene.add(ball)

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  controls.update()
    render()
    ballbb.copy(ball.geometry.boundingSphere).applyMatrix4(ball.matrixWorld)
    console.log(ball.position)

}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    ball.position.add(ball.userData.vel)
}
```

Comment: Does your code work without the line you've called out?

Comment: Yes, it works without it. However when I place the copy function above the render function I get the error ree.cjs:5084 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'center')
    at Sphere.copy (three.cjs:5084:1)
    at animate (c

Comment: By default, [`BufferGeometry.boundingSphere`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeometry#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.boundingSphere) is `null`. It does not get populated until either you or the render process call [`BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeometry#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere()).

Comment: I' ve added sphere.computeBoundingSphere() in the animate function but still the sphere is not moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some time to debug this and figured out the problem. It's a twisting tale, so hold on...

The `Sphere` constructor ([r152 source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r152/src/math/Sphere.js)) takes a `Vector3` as the center position, and a `Number` as the radius of the sphere being defined. The quirk comes in that the center `Vector3` isn't copied into `Sphere.center`, but is instead *assigned* to the property. This means `Sphere.center` will be a *reference to* the `Vector3` passed to it.

*But wait, there's more!*

In `three.js`, when you change `Mesh.position`, it won't update the `matrixWorld` right away unless you tell it to with `Object3D.updatematrixWorld()` or a call to `render`. So until that happens, `ball.matrixWorld` still holds the matrix from the *previous* update.

### An unfortunate chain of events...

1. You set `ball.position` (technically this also updates `ballbb.center`!)
2. You render the scene (this also automatically calls `Object3D.updateMatrixWorld()`)
3. You update `ball.position` (no auto-update to `ball.matrixWorld`)
4. You copy the geometry's bsphere (identity position) into `ballbb`
5. You apply `ball.matrixWorld` to `ballbb` (this multiplies is against `ballbb.center`)
6. Goto 1, repeat

### Analysis

**Step 4** is where things go sideways. When you copy the identity bounding sphere into `ballbb`, you destroy the update made in **Step 1**, not only for `ballbb`, but also for `ball`! Copying the identity resets `ballbb.center` (and, in turn, `ball.position`) to `(0, 0, 0)`. You then apply the `ball.MatrixWorld`, but because there hasn't been a `render` or `updateMatrixWorld` since **Step 2**, `ball.matrixWorld` is still the world matrix from the last render, so you're basically applying the transformation from the previous frame, meaning the ball doesn't move.

### How do you fix this?

You could probably rearrange your logic to ensure updating `ball.position` or `ballbb.center` are applied and propagated correctly, but I was able to fix it by changing one thing:

```js
var ballbb = new THREE.Sphere(ball.position.clone(), 70)
```

Notice the call to `Vector3.clone()`. This will ensure the `Vector3` given to the `Sphere` is a *copy* of `ball.position`, so that updates to one won't affect the other.

#### A better fix...

Really, you should be able to simplify your code and not do any of the math you're doing. When you create your `Sphere`, *do* give it `ball.position`, but then don't worry about doing anything else. When you update `ball.position`, it will also update `ballbb.center`. A `Sphere` doesn't have a `matrixWorld`, and all of its math is computed from the `center` and `radius` values, so it will "automatically" follow `ball`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the deep analysis! It was extremely helpful!! Very much appreciated.